# Why is Node's https module returning a 301 when the resource has not actually been moved?

Tags: node.js, api, https

I am trying to execute a simple HTTPS request to an external API using Node's native `https` module.

Using the deprecated `request` module, I can successfully retrieve the JSON response, so I know the API endpoint is correct, and that the resource exists.

So, my configuration using the `https` module must be incorrect, but I'm trying to understand why it would return a 301 specifically.

Is it possible by eyeballing the code snippet below to spot the problem?

```
const https = require("https");

const options = {
    hostname: 'lingq.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/api/languages',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Token xxxxxxxxxxx' }
};

https.get(options, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);  
}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: I haven't checked that, but I suspect that the `request` module can detect a `301` response code and automatically make another request to the new location and this is why you were able to get the JSON response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your target server `lingq.com` that is returning the 301, not your node.js server.

The `location` header that the target is returning is this:

```
location: 'https://www.lingq.com/api/languages'
```

so it appears that it wants you to use `www.lingq.com` as the host, not `lingq.com`.

**Your Specific Questions**

> Using the deprecated request module, I can successfully retrieve the JSON response, so I know the API endpoint is correct, and that the resource exists.

In the `request` module, the `followRedirect` option defaults to `true` so it will automatically follow 3xx redirects.

> So, my configuration using the https module must be incorrect, but I'm trying to understand why it would return a 301 specifically.

Because it wants you to be using `www.lingq.com` as the host, not `lingq.com`.

> Is it possible by eyeballing the code snippet below to spot the problem?

No.  I had to actually run the code and see the returned headers to see the different host in the location header.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do that. Indeed, the host should have been "www.lingq.com", but additionally, as I found, the path should have had an extra "/" at the end. Updating both now returns a 200. Thanks once again!

Comment: Actually I'm somewhat surprised the trailing slash was needed, given the content of the location header is "location: 'https://www.lingq.com/api/languages'"

Comment: @vordhosbn - Yep, their first 301 redirect isn't quite correct and therefore you get a 2nd 301 redirect to the path they actually want you to use.  That's a mistake on their part.  But, if your code just follows 301 redirects, it would just work anyway.